# Redirect certain HTTPS url with squid

Tags: squid

When passing all http and https traffic through squid3, is it possible if a user requests `http://www.example.com` I could redirect to a different url?

Would this only be possible for HTTP or HTTPS too?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

http://servercomputing.blogspot.com/2012/03/squid-proxy-redirect-url.html describes how to do it for HTTP.  HTTPs is probably not going to be possible unless you have squid set up to MITM all HTTPS sites, as you can't 30x a CONNECT request and squid is also unaware of the full request url. HTTPS hides that from the proxy.